# Why do I get Net::HTTP "request path is empty" error?

Tags: ruby, net-http

I'm using Net::HTTP to make a HTTP request. I get the error "HTTP request path is empty", but I strongly feel that it is not. The code is below:

```
REQUEST_IP = "localhost"
REQUEST_PORT = "8081"
REQUEST_PATH = "myweb/rest"

def customServiceMailAndMessageRequest user_id, message

  url = 'http://' + REQUEST_IP + ":" + REQUEST_PORT + "/" + REQUEST_PATH + '/users/' + user_id + '/messages/sendMailAndMessage?message=' + message
  uri = URI(url)

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
  request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  request['Accept'] = 'application/json'

  response = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port) do |http|
    http.request(request)
  end

  puts response

end
```

The error is:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1478:in `initialize': HTTP request path is empty (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1596:in `initialize'
```

Can anyone point towards my mistake?

Comment: Try `puts uri.path` before passing it to `Net::HTTP::Get.new`. I suspect it's coming from there and that your path is being mangled during the construction of the `url` variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I received a similar error when I didn't include a trailing `/`. As soon as I did, all was well.

From the information that you've shared, I can only assume that your `message` variable doesn't have that.